# I am trying to add status and playing status to my user info command

Tags: discord.js

I have an already exisiting user info command, and want to add the status (e.g dnd) and the game the user is playing (i.e Minecraft). I've tried `message.author.status` after looking through the docs, but it output `undefined` in my embed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This property doesn‘t exist for the client Object. You can check all properties and methods for the ClientUser **[here](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/ClientUser?scrollTo=presence)**.

To show the game that the user is currently playing, use:

```
message.author.presence.game
```

---

To show the current status of the user:

```
message.author.presence.status
```